# glsl pack two signed floats in one

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

In GLSL ES 2.0 
I want to pack 2 signed float values into alpha channel. 
Channel could be lowp or mediump. 
How can I do this?

P.S. I need this for my postprocessing/resolve pass, so I think pack/unpack overhead will be worth it.

Comment: When you say it can be `lowp` or `mediump`, are you referring to the floats you are packing, or the float you are trying to cram these into? And what is the range of your signed floats?

Comment: Moreover, since you are talking about multi-pass rendering here, are you outputting this to a normalized (fixed-point) image format? That is seriously going to hamper your ability to pack anything.

Comment: Fixed point should be ok.

Comment: I found a solution (from Unity standart shader package). But I can't understand how it works, because it not work with CPU http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74230/unitys-pack-4-floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Unity's UnityCG.cginc](https://gist.github.com/hecomi/9580605) :

```
// Encoding/decoding [0..1) floats into 8 bit/channel RGBA. Note that 1.0 will not be encoded properly.
inline float4 EncodeFloatRGBA( float v )
{
    float4 kEncodeMul = float4(1.0, 255.0, 65025.0, 160581375.0);
    float kEncodeBit = 1.0/255.0;
    float4 enc = kEncodeMul * v;
    enc = frac (enc);
    enc -= enc.yzww * kEncodeBit;
    return enc;
}
inline float DecodeFloatRGBA( float4 enc )
{
    float4 kDecodeDot = float4(1.0, 1/255.0, 1/65025.0, 1/160581375.0);
    return dot( enc, kDecodeDot );
}
```

But one must pay attention to stored packed/unpacked values, because they must be fraction of encoding base(255 here). For example 0.1 will not work here, but 25/255 = 0.098 is ok.
This what confused me much.

P.S. As Andon M. Coleman noted - we rather store integer values (divided by encoding base) than real floats.
P.P.S. It is better always to trim to nearest discrete value before pack (If you get it from some calculations)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to do this in ES 2.0 (and I don't believe this is possible).

There are, however, some new built-in functions in ES 3.0 that are designed for this if you're able to use ES 3.0:

```
highp uint packSnorm2x16(vec2 v)
highp vec2 unpackSnorm2x16(highp uint p)
highp uint packUnorm2x16(vec2 v)
highp vec2 unpackUnorm2x16(highp uint p)
```

These pack and unpack a pair of floats into a signed or unsigned normalized integer format that's smaller for storage.

There are also built-in functions that operate on mediump (half-)floats:

```
highp uint   packHalf2x16(mediump vec2 v)
mediump vec2 unpackHalf2x16(highp uint v)
```

You could also make use of the functions in ARB_shader_bit_encoding (part of ES 3.0), either in conjunction with those previously mentioned or separately to implement your own packing:

```
genIType floatBitsToInt(genType value)
genUType floatBitsToUint(genType value)

genType intBitsToFloat(genIType value)
genType uintBitsToFloat(genUType value)
```

They perform bit-casts from float to integral types.

ES 3.0 is backward compatible (modulo some corner cases) with ES 2.0. The obstacle is whether the hardware you're targeting can do ES 3.0. Good luck!

Comment: I even have no highp (16bit) float/vec values in ES 2.0. This will not work.